# Error con openCV (-215 Assertion Failded)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Tengo un codigo que me permite ver la webcam dentro de una qlabel y un boton `self.boton1` que esta conectado ala funcion `def take()` que es la encargada de tomar la fotografia.

PROBLEMA:

Al momento de presionar el boton la foto la toma y la guarda pero lanza el siguiente error y se detiene el programa:

`error: (-215: Assertion failed)! _src.empty () in the function 'cv :: cvtColor'`

este es el codigo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication
import cv2
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import uic


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("f.ui",self)

        self.boton1.clicked.connect(self.take)
        self.video_size = QtCore.QSize(320,240)
        self.setup_camera()

    def setup_camera(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 160)
        self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,self.video_size.height())
        #self.Bfoto.clicked.connect(lambda:self.take(self.capture))

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.display_video_stream)
        self.timer.start(30)

    def display_video_stream(self):
        _,frame  =self.capture.read()
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)
        image = QtGui.QImage(frame,frame.shape[1],frame.shape[0],frame.strides[0],QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))

    def take(self):
        print("value")
        cap = self.capture
        leido,frame = cap.read()

        if leido ==True:
            cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/photo.jpg",frame)
            print("ok")
        else:
            print("error")
        cap.release()
app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

f.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>441</width>
      <height>311</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>TextLabel</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="boton1">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>430</x>
      <y>400</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Este es el error completo que manda:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\s.py", line 30, in display_video_stream
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
[Finished in 5.2s with exit code 3]`

Comment: @AngelJudathAlvarez, el error esta en la indentacion despues del ultimo else: en el `cap.releasse()` que esta fuera de lugar